# Knife laws in multiple European countries on train

Tags: trains, europe, legal

I am going to make an Interrail trip in September this year, which will be a mix of rural camping and city trips. Due to the camping, I am considering taking my Mora Garberg (blade length: 10.9cm, blade width: 3.2mm) with me, but I am unsure about the laws and how the different train companies handle this topic.

I am planning on starting in Barcelona and continuing to Rome via Toulon. After that going to Slovenia, Austria, and Germany.

I thought of packing the knife into my sleeping bag (unlikely to be searched), but I don't want any trouble with the authorities. I am considering workarounds, e.g. my small Swiss pocket knife, but I am unsure if even that is illegal.

I don't carry it in the pocket of my pants when I am e.g. walking through Rome, but I am afraid of e.g. someone searching my backpack when crossing borders.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knife_legislation

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. You are a EU resident, so I would expect you know there are no border checks within the Schengen area, and trains (apart from a few exception) do not have luggage scanners.

Comment: @KristvanBesien I am aware that there are no such things as luggage scanners on trains except Eurostar. But border police officers, at least in Germany, have permission to search your luggage if you are crossing the border into Germany. That is what I am afraid of. In addition, there are sometimes border controls, where certain travelers are picked for investigation. For example, if you take the IC from Hamburg to Copenhagen, the Danish border police will go through the train and check the ID Card of every traveler.

Comment: They will not search luggage of normal passengers though. They do not have the time and manpower for that. They will do it if they got a tip you have a cut up corpse in there or something...

Comment: The exact rules differ by country, and seem to be more related to the type of knife than it's size, e.g. no double-edged knives etc. Between Spain, France and Italy, France looks the most strict, with a blade limit of 3". Also, in all three, you need to have a proper reason to carry a knife, in Spain, you can't display it in public places, etc etc. In short, there isn't a single answer. It's probably best to Google "knife law (country)" for all countries you'll be visiting

Comment: IMO, it's beyond obvious that the Mora knives are intended for camping and outdoor use. They are not combat knives by any means. I seriously doubt it could lead to any problems even if the authorities find out you're carrying one.

Comment: In some countries it also differs by city. I did not see the Netherlands in your list but if you do come check at city level, Amsterdam for instance forbids all knives in most of the city and there are more cities like that.

Comment: Many, many years ago, I remember going on a trip around the US on train and plane - never a problem with a steak knife (with food in the same bag) on a train (nobody checked anything) or a plane (*in carry-on, clearly visible*). Times have changed. But the concerns on a train are far, far, less than on a plane.

Comment: "there are no such things as luggage scanners on trains except Eurostar" - in Spain there are luggage scanners for the high-speed trains

Comment: Don't hide it in your sleeping bag.  This just makes it look you are hiding it for some reason.  Pack it with the rest of your kitchen, properly protected if you are worried about damaging other gear in your backpack.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko, in the UK at least, broadly speaking, a knife is a knife*.  If you're carrying any form of blade without good reason, you can expect a penalty.  The fact that it is "beyond obvious[ly]...intended for camping" is unlikely to cut any ice with the police if you're just carrying it around. Of course, "I'm on a camping trip through Europe", is probably going to be a valid explanation if they found it while looking through your bag. *_Certain classes of knives_ are _illegal to possess in any circumstances.  They aren't the kind of thing you carry on a camping trip though._

Comment: @BWFC This question is not about the UK; I know UK laws are very fussy about knives. However, if I'm heading to a national park with my outdoor gear that includes a Mora knife or a Swiss Army knife, I don't see how that can be a problem in the UK.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko, I understand the question isn't about the UK but I was trying to make the point (no pun intended) about a knife being a knife.  I expect in many other places, there's no distinction between a combat knife and camping knife.  And you're correct in that if you're heading to a National Park with your Mora knife it probably won't be a problem.  However, if it's strapped to your belt on a crowded train, the police will almost certainly take a dimmer view of it than if it's tucked neatly in your bag on a luggage rack.

Comment: Note that in addition to state legislations and train operators there are some _train stations_ that explicitly ban knives. It will be hard to give an exhaustive list of these local regulations, but should be clearly signed if so. If you do not want to have trouble with local security, pack your knife reasonably away as already suggested here, and do not peel your apple while waiting for a train.

Comment: Spains rail operator bans knives greater than 6 cm in blade length. See [the relevant policy in Spanish](https://www.renfe.com/es/es/normativa?anchor=ObjetosnoPermitidos) Relevant section is "Objetos no permitidos"

Comment: @BWFC even in UK law a knife is _not_ always a knife. Knives with a cutting edge less than 3" that are not "lock knives" are classed as folding pocketknives and are generally legal to carry

Comment: In some 50 years of camping I've never needed a blade such as you propose. Something to think about.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quite generally:

- You should check the rules per country on Wikipedia's [Knife Legislation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knife_legislation) page.
- In some countries some types of knives are forbidden altogether, because their only purpose is to be used as weapons.
- In many cases, the destination (in the sense "what do you intend to do with the knife", not "where are you going to") is relevant: having a kitchen knife in hand or in your pocket is very different from having a kitchen knife in a box or closed bag.
- I'm not aware of any systematic scans or checks anywhere (except Eurostar to/from London, which seems to be outside the scope of your question) and on high-speed services in Spain. Not familiar with Renfe's policies, but on the Eurostar they could bother you for nail clippers when departing from London while the guys in Paris (french customs officers) don't care the least. Bad movies notwithstanding, since it's going to be quite difficult to hijack a train, they should be more worried about guns (as in Thalys attack) and bombs (as in TGV bombing), but YMMV.
- The UK is probably the country with the most restrictions (and the only one I know with big posters at Saint Pancras telling you that knives are forbidden), but again, out of scope of your question.
- At borders between the countries listed in your question, there are no systematic checks anywhere. The only place they **could** have systematic checks is when you enter/exit the EU, i.e. when you go through Switzerland, but they definitely don't. They can do random checks, but as far as I know they are more interested in drugs (especially on routes from the Netherlands) and money (on routes to/from Switzerland).
- While at some borders there may be systematic passport control checks (due to "temporary" reintroduction of border checks between Schengen Area member states), those usually apply only one-way (basically South-to-North or East-to-West), and involve immigration, so passports and visas, rather than your belongings. Depending on the border the agents doing immigration and customs checks may or may not be the same, or they may do joint patrols, but still, what they are looking for is in my experience quite specific.
- One possible issue is that some "types" have a tendency to draw law enforcement like magnets. "Foreign-looking" people (especially from Africa, the Middle-East and South Asia) draw immigration and police looking for illegal migrants. Others like backpackers draw customs and police looking for drugs. While searching for those they may end up finding your knife, but that's usually not what they were looking after.

As others have advised, don't try to hide anything. Make sure the knife is not a type that is explicitly forbidden. Do not carry it in your pocket, but in a well-closed (ideally locked) box or bag, making it clear that there is no intent to use it.

Comment: In fairness, it would be at least mildly surprising if any _other_ countries had big posters at Saint Pancras about anything.

Comment: Spain's train operator (Renfe) bans knives except for a few not applicable exceptions. See [the relevant policy in Spanish](https://www.renfe.com/es/es/normativa?anchor=ObjetosnoPermitidos).
The relevant section (Objetos no permitidos (Forbidden Objects)) translates as:
[...]
Sharp objects:
[...]
-Knifes with a blade length greater than 6 centimeters.
[...]

Comment: Spain absolutely will scan your bags before letting you board an high speed train. I don't know what they do about knives, but I have always had to scan my bags. At least for Madrid, Barcelona and Valencia.

Comment: "The UK is probably the country with the most restrictions", and also the one where you will never have anything scanned or searched, minus the Eurostar.

Answer (score 21):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

Some styles of knife are forbidden. They include [butterfly knives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_knife), [push knives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_dagger), or disguised knives. Since they cannot be owned, they cannot be carried.

Other styles of knife are restricted from carry in the public. This includes blade lengths over 12 cm, or folding knives which can be operated with a single hand. There are exceptions from this restriction, plenty of kitchen knives are longer than 12 cm. These exceptions come down to "good reason" and "reasonable stowage." A picknick basket may contain a longer knife, but you can't wear it on the belt in a pub.

As I understand it, you have a fixed knife with a blade shorter than that. So don't *hide* it in the sleeping bag, *pack it with your kitchen stuff* along with spoons and forks. And pack the kitchen stuff so that there can be no suggestion that it is *ready to draw*.

Comment: OP lists a very specific knife though - is it banned anywhere on their route?

Comment: @JonathanReez, my answer is tagged with one country on the route, and the answer is in my last paragraph.

Comment: *"And pack the kitchen stuff so that there can be no suggestion that it is ready to draw."* Is it really illegal to carry a knife in a  belt holster? This site says that *"Fixed blades with blade length under 12 cm (4.72 in.) can be carried visible or concealed."* https://knife-blog.com/german-knife-law/

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава, there are special rules in some areas. By clearly treating the knife as a kitchen implement, one avoids trouble.

Answer (score 10):

There are only two train companies that are interested in what is in your luggage. Eurostar scans your luggage on UK - Continent services. RENFE pretends to scan your luggage when boarding a high speed train (but you can just put the knife in a jacket pocket if you want to avoid questions.

In all other countries there are no pre boarding procedures, other than in some services a ticket check. So do not worry about what you have in your luggage. And nobody will search your luggage when crossing borders as that is pretty much a non event within the Schengen Area these days.

Comment: I have been checked, luggage through a scanner and people through a metal detector, in France on what at that time was the Thalys. In case of the Eurostar (which is now merged with the Thalys) it is also a combination of scanner and metal detector. I would leave the knife in the luggage rather than put it in a pocket.

Comment: This addresses the practicalities, but not the question of legality. If the half-assed RENFE checks find a knife, will they be mad about it? If you want to avoid trouble with the police in another county, is it bad if a knife falls out of your sleeping bag? You can surely get away with bringing more dangerous things onto trains some of the time, but it still may not be legal.

Comment: Thalys at one time did indeed experiment with luggage scanning. They fortunately found it it was pointless and stopped with it.
I always have a Victorinox Swisstool with me when I travel. On a train never an issue.

Comment: @mlc I'm pretty sure I went through the RENFE checks once with picknick stuff including at least one knife and no one cared, but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: Putting your knife in your jacket pocket is terrible advice. You are far more likely to get in trouble for carrying a knife where it can be easily accessed than having one safely in your luggage.

Comment: While that may be true for train companies, they are not the only ones who search your luggage. I've been searched by border police crossing from Germany to Austria and they have legal rights to search my backpack without consent (only within 20km or so near the border)